# How do I make iTunes re-remember an app I have recently requested it to forget?

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications, icloud

In the iTunes home tab (on your Mac) there is a section known as a "quick link" section where you can view all of your purchased apps.  It's on the right hand side and it has a hyperlink aptly named "purchased."

Here you can view all of the apps you have downloaded to your device.

If you hover over any app icon there is a small "x" that appears in the upper-left hand corner of the app icon.  If you hit that "x" iTunes will forget that you have purchased that app and it will no longer download it from iCloud.  When you search for the app in the app store there will no longer be a cloud it will just have a box that reads "free."

Well, within the last week any app that you have requested for iTunes to forget will now leave you in this never ending loop of a dialog box that reads "this item is free in the store.  This item will be added to your Purchases, and will be available even if your Family Sharing status changes." It gives you the option to "cancel" or to "download."

I can click download before I put in my password for my app ID or afterwards.  Doesn't matter because this will put me in a never ending loop of this dialog box (never ending if you want to download).

I cannot find any answers to this. I have seen it asked once already but none of the answers helped.

This dialog box does not pop up for any new apps I have or any previous apps I have still known to iCloud.  It only pops up for any app that I have previously requested that iCloud forget about.

I am thinking I can bypass this problem if I can have iTunes re-remember the app, but I am at a loss as to how to do that.

Comment: This pop-up has been reported in multiple questions this week. In all cases it's been related to App Store overload thanks to the iPhone 6 release. Please see: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145106/app-store-is-stuck-in-a-loop-trying-to-download-a-free-app-how-do-i-make-it-s

Comment: I've read that. Doesn't give me an issue when I'm downloading any apps other than the ones I've listed. Still would like to know if there is a way for iTunes to re-remember the apps I've installed. Is there an answer for that question?

Comment: The core question you're asking is excellent and I don't think it's been asked before. I mentioned the other Q&A because it may be tangential to what you want to accomplish.